# passing variable from middleware to end function

Tags: go

im using a middleware (`CheckToken`) to check a JWT and get the custom claim (`Id`) (it will be the id of the user on my DB) but i need to pass it to campaign.Attack (so i can know who is the user who is doing the "attack") but i cant find out a way to do it.

i tried to pass it as a parameter in `next(w, req, claim.id)` in `token.go` but i would need to touch the `http.HandlerFunc` function so this isnt a valid option.

any idea about how to pass the `claim.id` from `CheckToken`  to `campaign.Attack()` ?

thank you

```
         ***** main.go*****

            func main() {

                router := mux.NewRouter()

                router.HandleFunc("/attack", token.CheckToken(campaign.Attack)).Methods("GET", "OPTIONS")

               log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":3000", handlers.CORS(handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"}),
                    handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"Content-Type", "authorization"}))(router)))
            }



            ******campaign.go*****

            package campaign

            import (
                "log"
                "net/http"

            )


            func init() {

            }

            func Attack(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
                log.Println("attack")

                //i need to get the claim.Id here
            }


            ****token.go****

type MyCustomClaims struct {
    Id int `json:"id"`  //the Id of the user 
    jwt.StandardClaims
}

            func CheckToken(next http.HandlerFunc) (MyCustomClaims, http.HandlerFunc) {
                return MyCustomClaims{}, http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

                    authorizationHeader := req.Header.Get("authorization")
                    if authorizationHeader != "" {
                        bearerToken := strings.Split(authorizationHeader, " ")
                        if len(bearerToken) == 2 {
                            token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(bearerToken[1], &MyCustomClaims{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
                                return []byte("magicword"), nil
                            })

                            if token.Valid {


                                if claims, ok := token.Claims.(*MyCustomClaims); ok && token.Valid {
                               //**************************
                              //***********i have the claims.id here and it works.*******
                              //**************************
                                    log.Println(claims.Id)

                              //but i need to pass it or find a way to read it in campaign.Attack()
                                    next(w, req)
                                } else {
                                    log.Println(err)
                                }
                            } else if ve, ok := err.(*jwt.ValidationError); ok {
                                if ve.Errors&jwt.ValidationErrorMalformed != 0 {


                                } else if ve.Errors&(jwt.ValidationErrorExpired|jwt.ValidationErrorNotValidYet) != 0 {
                                    // Token is either expired or not active yet

                                } 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 


                })

            }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to hide campaign.Attack's dependency on CheckToken with a middleware. Consider changing Attack to func(*http.Request) (MyCustomClaims, error) and just call it in campaign.Attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into CheckToken .. It should be middleware, and typical midleware pass http.Handler and maybe another argument and return another http.Handler (this is bit better than using http.HandlerFunc). Returned function typically call argument and do some action before or after this call.

```
func CheckToken(next http.Handler) http.Handler
{
   return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
     // and body the same as you have in the answer, but instead of next(w, req) put there two lines "WithValue"
   }
}
```

and into begin of Attack put next few lines that I've already give you

Answer (score 1):

Use context's method WithValue. 
Instead next(w, req) write

```
   ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "claim_id", claims.Id)
   next(w, req.WithContext(ctx))
```

and inside attack:

```
   claim_id, ok := r.Context().Value("claim_id").(int)
   if !ok {
     return // I don't have context .. sorry
   }
   // use claim_id
```

What I haven't mention, how to create an unique key ... but sometimes in the future.

Comment: i get this error: .\main.go:115:49: multiple-value token.CheckToken() in single-value context

Comment: It make sense .. CheckToken returns two things (MyCustomClaims + http.HandlerFunc), but router.HandleFunc needs only HandlerFunc. Why you tries to return both, not only HandlerFunc? CheckToken could not return reasonable Claims, becase it it called before first request appear.

Comment: then how could i get in campaign.Attack the information of claims.Id? i need to know in the attack function the id of the user who sends me the token in the "authorization: bearer TOKEN_HERE"
if there were something like a global variable to store it and retrieve from there later.

Comment: look into my first answer and think - When any request appears, I have to somehow add some supplementary information to request in middleware. How I can do it? By creating a new request with context where I add this information. That is what I've done - first line is creating new context, clone it and add a new information under the key "claim_id". In the second line I've pass this new context into next function - I our case into Attack. And how I can obtain it? By calling Context's method value. But it returns me interface{} - it could be everything, therefore I will try cast it into int.

Comment: ok i understand the solution that you have proposed but what do i need to change to solve the error of: .\main.go:115:49: multiple-value token.CheckToken() in single-value context.  sorry for the annoyance